# Build a multi level array from a has many relationship

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I am building a basic CMS in Laravel 5.2.

I have a 'pages' model. This model has a 'has many' relationship with itself as a page can have many sub pages and a sub page can have many sub sub pages etc.

My model is defined as such:

```
class Page extends Model
{
    public function children()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Page', 'page_parent');
    }
}
```

My Database  is like so

```
+----+-----------------+------------------------+------------+-------------+
| id | title           | description            | project_id | page_parent |
+----+-----------------+------------------------+------------+-------------+
|  1 | Overview        | The overview page      |          1 |           0 |
|  2 | Overview sub    | Child page             |          1 |           1 |
|  3 | Very young page | This is the kiddy page |          1 |           2 |
+----+-----------------+------------------------+------------+-------------+
```

Then in my controller I have:

```
public function index()
{
    $pages = Page::with('children')->get();
    return Response()->json($pages, 200);
}
```

**What this does:**
This returns the pages as expected, however, the pages are only one level deep with one level in the 'children' object like so:

```
[
   {
      "id":1,
      "title":"Overview",
      "description":"The overview page",
      "project_id":"1",
      "page_parent":"0",
      "children":[
         {
            "id":2,
            "title":"Overview sub",
            "description":"Child page",
            "project_id":"1",
            "page_parent":"1",
         }
      ]
   },
   {
      "id":2,
      "title":"Overview sub",
      "description":"Child page",
      "project_id":"1",
      "page_parent":"1",
      "children":[
         {
            "id":3,
            "title":"Very young page",
            "description":"This is the kiddy page",
            "project_id":"1",
            "page_parent":"2"
         }
      ]
   },
   {
      "id":3,
      "title":"Very young page",
      "description":"This is the kiddy page",
      "project_id":"1",
      "page_parent":"2",
      "children":[

      ]
   }
   ]
```

**What I want**
What would be better for my front end dev is for there to be only one root JSON object (the top level page) and then the 'children' object recurse into itself to build a multi level tree of the pages like so:

```
[
{
      "id":1,
      "title":"Overview",
      "description":"The overview page",
      "project_id":"1",
      "page_parent":"0",
      "children":[
         {
            "id":2,
            "title":"Overview sub",
            "description":"Child page",
            "project_id":"1",
            "page_parent":"1",
            "children":[
            {
                 [
                 "id":3,
                 "title":"Very young page",
                 "description":"This is the kiddy page",
                 "project_id":"1",
                 "page_parent":"2",
                 "children":[

                 ]
                 ]
            }
            ]
         }
      ]
   },
]
```

I can think of a few hacky ways, but want to know what is the best 'Laravel way'. Should I be using an accessor or something like that?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this:

```
$pages = Page::with('children')->get()->toJson();
```

This also works:

```
$pages = Page::with('children')->get()->groupBy('page_parent')->toJson();
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply but that's pretty much what I already have and returns the 'linear' version of the JSON rather than the recursive objects I need

Comment: I'm 100% sure it returns multilevel array. I have a project with Category which has `parent_id` field, which is also a category. In your code you have just `->get();`, have you tried `->get()->toJson();`?